# Python 3: Generate byte stream using 'with'

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

What I'd like to do is generate a byte stream of arbitrary length. The reason for this, is because I need to essentially generate a file of arbitrary size. (For some background, I tried to stream a sparse file but [had trouble when the file sizes were large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856942/python3-open-large-sparse-file-throws-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument), so instead I'm trying to generate the bytes on the fly instead.)

I've been reading the documentation to make objects work with `with`, and I'm struggling to make this correctly. Here's what I've been attempting after trial and error, but still doesn't work. I think I'm missing something, but I honestly don't know what.

```
class BinaryGenerator:
    def __init__(self, size_in_mbs):
        self.size_in_mbs = size_in_mbs

    def __enter__(self):
        yield self.__bytes_generator__(self.size_in_mbs)
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def __bytes_generator__(mega_bytes):
        for i in range(mega_bytes * 1024):
            yield b'\x00'

def __write_size__(size):
    with open('arbitrary-{}mb.bin'.format(size), 'wb') as file:
        with BinaryGenerator(size) as binary:
            file.write(binary)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __write_size__(1)
```

I'll actually use this with [Requests Streaming Uploads](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads) but I'm trying to use this as a test to see if I can replicate the binary stream of data you get when you open a file using `with`

Comment: I think that names with double underscores before and after are meant to be special in Python, reserved for the workings of the language itself. You probably shouldn't do that. Go ahead and keep the leading underscores (that makes it private) but lose the trailing ones.

Comment: More to the point, can you be more specific about what doesn't work in this code?

Comment: I suspect the actual issue here is that the OP is confused about the difference between with-statement context managers and file-like objects. For the described purpose (simulating an arbitrary-sized file of constant bytes) a context manager is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure that you have understood what the context manager (the thing you use with `with`) does? Because you are mixing [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and context managers incorrectly (you don't `yield` from `__enter__()`). And from your problem statement, what you actually want is only a generator that returns your byte stream in chunks.

Comment: BCqrstoO: Expanding on my last comment, do you understand that it's the `open` function (or, more pedantically, the `file` constructor, which the `open` function is an alias of) that **opens** the file, while the `with` statement is only responsible for **closing** it? You don't need a `with` statement at all if the thing you're creating doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: @DanielPryden, I think that makes sense. So I have misunderstood my problem. I thought that by fulfilling the method contracts for `with` I would be able to pass that to `Requests`, however, what I SHOULD be doing is finding out how Requests is using the `file` object and implement my generator to supply Requests with data in whatever way it's polling that from file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record

- a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) is used, when you have an object that has an initialization and a cleanup function. In the example, it is used with a file object. Since file objects implement the context manager protocol, exiting the `with` block with a file handle will automatically close the file.

  `with open('arbitrary-{}mb.bin'.format(size), 'wb') as fd: ...`
- [a generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is a function that (programmatically) generates iterable results. One can think of it as a function that returns multiple times.

As for your problem: You can use a generator to implement result streaming, this is basically what they are for:

```
def bytes_generator(mega_bytes):
    for i in range(mega_bytes * 1024):
        yield b'\x00'

def write_size(size):
    with open('arbitrary-{}mb.bin'.format(size), 'wb') as fd:
         for b in bytes_generator(size):
              fd.write(b)
```

This is woefully inefficient, though, since it writes a single byte at a time. But to fix it, you only need to modify the chunking from the generator.

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) explicitly allow for chunked uploads via generators.

```
def gen():
    yield 'hi'
    yield 'there'

requests.post('http://some.url/chunked', data=gen())
```